# Field level edit is now available even if we have customized our edit form using "Script Editor"

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration, modern-experience

I have the following:-

1. Custom list inside a classic Team Site.
2. i have customized the Edit form using Script editor classic web part. this result that the edit form will render using classic UI which is fine. while the New and Display form will render using Moderm UI which is also fine with me.
3. so now my Create & Display forms are been rendered using Modern UI, while my Edit form is been rendered using the Classic UI(since i have customized the edit form using script editor web part).
4. Also previously (last time i check it was around 6 months ago), field level edit options inside the Display form were also disabled, and i thought this is the case since i have customized my edit form, here is the field level edit i am talking about:-

[image]

but last week i have noted that the users are able to do field level edit.. so this is causing problems because inside the edit form i have disabled some fields based on other fields' values.. but the field level option will always allow the users to edit all the fields regardless of any other factors... so how i can fix this issue? is there any workaround to disable the field level edit on the fields inside the display form?

Comment: As far as I know, this is a by design phenomenon. So far there is no alternative solution.

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT so how Microsoft is approaching this ? there is a setting to disable Quick Edit, so we can force the users to edit the list item using the Edit form which contain our customization (which is inside a script editor web part)... but at the same time there is no option to disable item-level edit for the list items... does not make sense at all......

Comment: I suggest you open a service request.

Comment: @Binggo_MSFT i do not think Microsoft will fix this for us, as seems it is a global behavior ...

Answer (score 0):

Users are able now to edit fields directly from the display form. The only option to prevent this behavior is designing a custom display form. I can recommend using Power Apps or [Plumsail Forms](https://plumsail.com/forms/) for creating custom forms for *modern UI* in SharePoint.